# Create internal private network for VMs

Tags: linux, networking, proxmox

I have a linux server with some VMs (proxmox).

Currently, they each have a public IP assigned from a rather small block, let's say 200.0.0.0/28, and I'm running out of address space for new VMs. This is achieved with a bridge interface `vmbr0` bridged to the physical interface `eno1`.

Now, I want to create an internal network (let's say 10.0.95.0/24) to give to new internal VMs. This internal network should also have NAT, so that the VMs can communicate with the outside world for downloading packages etc.

How can I achieve this? Even already knowing what I'm looking for is called would be of great help :)

---

I already tried reading through [the proxmox network config docs](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration), but none of the options really match the hybrid setup I want to have here. I.e. retain the bridge network for the existing VMs, but *add* an internal network with masquerading.

I assume what I want is some kind of VLAN, as part of the existing `vmbr0`. I.e. a VLAN on the host.

I also tried various setups with `/etc/network/interfaces`, but without the desired result unfortunately.

---

For reference, these are the relevant parts of my current `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 200.0.0.32/24
        gateway 200.0.0.1
        bridge-ports eno1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

Comment: "How can I achieve this?" I'm not familiar with proxmox, but generally, the solution is simply "create another bridge device". Interfaces attached to that bridge device will form a private network. If a vm is connected to both `vmbr0` and to this new interface, it can act as a router for other vms that are only attached to the private network.

Comment: https://blog.jenningsga.com/private-network-with-proxmox/